# Wordpress при загрузке медиафайла png система автоматически меняет тип файла на jpg

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress при загрузке медиафайла png система автоматически меняет тип файла на jpg. Подскажите, кто знает куда покопать?

Comment: нашел в чем баг. Если кому-то пригодится, а пригодится явно, потому как у народа в Сети есть подобные запросы. Начал смотреть "волшебные" плагины от кривых рук и нашел вот это у себя: Better Images. После деактивации этого плагина все стало на свои места. Не советую устанавливать, лучше писать самому, если есть время

Comment: Это первое дело при поиске ошибок в WP - отключить все плагины и сменить тему на стандартную.